# FHIR - What are profiled resources in FHIR Specification

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I've read it on some websites about the term **profiled resources** for example:

> Vonk FHIR Server supports all resource types and search parameters in the FHIR specification, including profiled resources.

But I'm not sure about the term profiled resource here. I tried to search it but couldn't get satisfactory definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profiled resources are those that conform to a specific profile which constraints them further from the base specification. [[1]](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/profiling.html)